# Common Charger/Alternate Solution for iPad (new), Macbook Retina, iPhone5

Tags: ipad, macbook-pro, iphone, charger

I just recently did an upgrade to all apple products and have a retina Macbook Pro, an iPhone 5, and an iPad.

I hate having to carry around 3 different chargers. I was wondering if there is an adapter, or something else that I can carry around instead. I wouldn't mind having 2 adapters that go into 1 charger, since that is better than 3 chargers. Basically

```
iPad ----------Ad
iPhone----------|-------------Power
Macbook--------Ad
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated, since I haven't really found anyone else with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While an iPad typically charges very slowly on a regular USB port, you could still use your MacBook Pro's USB ports to charge your devices. You definitely can charge your iPhone using your computer's USB port.

There also exists an accessory to "plug" a 10W USB port onto your MacBook Pro power adapter called [PlugBug](http://twelvesouth.com/products/plugbug/). This should be fine for charging your iPad.

Comment: I was going to suggest this - the PlugBug is amazing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

- one charger for both the iPad and the iPhone and another one for the MacBook
- one charger for the MacBook and then (slowly) charge the iDevices via the MacBook

Answer (score 0):

Since Apple is not licensing its Magsafe connector you will not be able to buy some kind of universal power supply.

As of now there are also no third party products with Lighting connector. So best you can do is to use [Lightning to 30 pin Dock Connector adaptor](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD823ZM/A/lightning-to-30-pin-adapter) with your iPad cable to charge and sync iPhone 5